# PDE: if ∂t, ∂x , ∂x∂t exist at the same time how to separate it to differential equations??

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In an PDE, if these kind of equation: $\frac{\partial \:u\left(x,\:t\right)}{\partial \:t}+\frac{\partial ^2u\left(x,\:t\right)}{\partial \:x\partial \:t}+\frac{\partial ^2u\left(x,\:t\right)}{\partial \:x^2}=0 $

How can i deal with it?

Am i doing right??
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going in the right direction. Starting with $X(x)T'(t)+X'(x)T'(t)=-X''(x)T(t)$ we can obtain $$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)+X'(x)}=\lambda$$ where $\lambda$ is some constant. We can do this because two functions with different variables can be equal only when they are constants. Thus, we obtain two equations to find $T(t)$ and $X(x)$:
  $\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\lambda$ and $-\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)+X'(x)}=\lambda$

Comment: Thankyou! that's help a lot! Cuz I have never seen a question like this before. X(

Comment: You are welcome!